# how to create new core - Solr 3.x

Tags: tomcat, solr, centos

I want to create a new core to index jobresumes. so I just copy the existing one and renamed 'jobresumes' and edited the fields in schema.xml in that copied folder and cleaned up the data folder. Then added the core command in solr.xml file. restarted the Tomcat but no luck.

Is any other way to create a new core?

Comment: Does the log say anything useful about your new core? i.e. it should show an error that it can't be loaded if it's attempting to load it but fails..

Comment: I checked tomcat logs. it shows - "Feb 18, 2019 10:26:56 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: SessionListener: contextInitialized()".

Comment: I tried to addDocument using php code. it shows "404" Status: Not Found

Comment: That message from the logs isn't related to core initialization. Search through the log properly and look for the names of the core.

Comment: yes. it shows "Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't find resource 'solrconfig.xml' in classpath or '/home/solr/apache-solr-3.4.0/jobresumes/admin/conf/', cwd=/" - but how to resolve this?

Comment: I'd start by adding solrconfig.xml in the expected location - additionally I'm not sure about the `admin` part of the subdirectory - are you sure your core path is set correct?

Comment: yes, core path is correct . do I need anything to change on solrconfig.xml which is in jobresumes/conf folder?

Comment: But that's not the path it's trying to load the `solrconfig.xml` from ..

Comment: then where have to load solrconfig.xml? can you please tell me the flow?

Comment: It's looking for the solrconfig.xml file in `/home/solr/apache-solr-3.4.0/jobresumes/admin/conf/` - if that's not where it's located, your path is wrong somewhere (i.e. maybe `admin` shouldn't be there, or your cores live in a different path by default)